# How to setup replication from on-premise Postgresql DB to AWS RDS Postgresql DB

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a PostgreSQL DB instance with some data. I also have a fresh RDS instance.
I want to set up a physical replication of the on-premise database to Amazon RDS. The data on RDS needs to be in sync with the on-premise database. I would like the data to be copied first and any updates to the on-premise database should reflect to the RDS instance.